# Google indexing pages that are not used

Tags: search, seo

I am using wp site that was built on template downloaded from internet and uploaded demo content of theme.
There are bunch of pages that I am not using. They can not be accessed from website but I see that Google is indexing them.

Question:
What is best practice? Should i delete all those pages that i am not using ( I wonder maybe later i will need them) or I can modify sitemap file when submiting to Search Console?
Does it impacts SEO?

Any help apriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should enter the editor of your pages, and as you see for example [here](https://crocoblock.com/knowledge-base/articles/how-to-change-the-pages-visibility-settings/), on the right side settings you can control their "visibility". Change that to "private", and then Google won't see them. Once Google will reindex your pages, these should disappear from its search results. And until then, visitors will see a "404 - Page not found" page, when they try to access them. The SEO of the pages you want to keep, won't be affected by this.